# Magento: catching a placed order, but the transaction id is empty

Tags: magento

I want to catch all placed order with an observer to use the data in a further process.
In my Observer I wrote:

```
class Custom_CrmApi_Model_Observer extends Varien_Object {
….
public function placeOrder( $observer ){

    $order = $observer->getOrder();
    $payment = $order->getPayment();

            $transId = $order->getPayment()->getTransactionId();           
            //$transId = $order->getPayment()->getLastTransId();
....
```

But the transaction ID of all ebay orders is empty (but not in the backend). I am using the M2E extension for ebay integration. But that shouldn’t be the problem, because the observer catch any placed order, or? At this time the transaction Id supposed to be available. But for some reason it isn’t available.

Any ideas? Perhaps a work around?

Thank you so much in advanced,

Hannes

Comment: Anyone a solution? I still couldn't get rid of this problem...please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It may be too late for you but maybe works for someone else.

I used this code to get the Transaction id for my report. It is on a different place then the normal ones for m2epro orders.

```
            $additional_data = $order->getPayment()->getData();
            //print_r($additional_data['additional_data']);
            $component_mode = $additional_data['additional_data'];
```

additional_data in payment gives you the information about the transaction. 
I am getting channel, payment, channel_order_id, channel_final_fee, transaction_id, fee, sum and transaction_date from aditional_data of the order. It is possible to get the same data from the same place on placeOrder function in m2epro.

app\code\community\Ess\M2ePro\Model\Magento\Order.php  -> placeOrder

```
    if (version_compare(Mage::helper('M2ePro/Magento')->getVersion(false), '1.4.1', '>=')) {
        /** @var $service Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote */
        $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $this->quote);
        $service->submitAll();

        // You can get this order before you return it and get the data maybe! 
        return $service->getOrder();         
   }
```

Worths to try.

Cheers